# Significance (or lack thereof) of the number of questions per user

Tags: discussion, site-statistics, stackexchange

I recently calculated the number of questions per user for all Stack Exchange sites with more than 10,000 questions. The data was taken from [the main Stack Exchange page listing all the sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), and I rounded to the nearest 1/100. (Obviously all data is only accurate as of now and can change in the future).

The results below show that Mi Yodeya has far and away the highest number of questions per user. While 4/5 of the sites do not even have one question per user, Mi Yodeya has an astounding 2.6 questions per users! The average for all other sites is .75 questions per user.

Does this tell us anything enlightening about Mi Yodeya?

Why is it that we have so many more questions per user than every other site?

Is this good, bad, or irrelevant?

Is there anything we could or should be doing to change this?

---

### Results

1. **Mi Yodeya**

   2.60
2. **Mathematics**

   2.11
3. **ExpressionEngine® Answers**

   2.11
4. **Salseforce**

   1.93
5. **Stack Overflow на русском**

   1.78
6. **Stack Overflow**

   1.70
7. **Craft CMS**

   1.64
8. **SharePoint**

   1.60
9. **Magento**

   1.55
10. **Drupal Answers**

    1.40
11. **Mathematica**

    1.34
12. **Русский язык**

    1.27
13. **Geographic Information Systems**

    1.26
14. **Tex La-Tex**

    1.18
15. **Stack Overflow em Português**

    1.17
16. **MathOverflow**

    1.14
17. **Blender**

    0.96
18. **Emacs**

    0.93
19. **Japanese Language**

    0.89
20. **スタック・オーバーフロー**

    0.89
21. **Role-playing Games**

    0.88
22. **Physics**

    0.87
23. **English Language Learners**

    0.86
24. **WordPress Development**

    0.79
25. **Gardening & Landscaping**

    0.77
26. **Electrical Engineering**

    0.75
27. **Stack Overflow en español**

    0.75
28. **Cross Validated**

    0.73
29. **Server Fault**

    0.70
30. **Home Improvement**

    0.67
31. **Law**

    0.67
32. **Arqade**

    0.66
33. **Biology**

    0.66
34. **Science Fiction & Fantasy**

    0.65
35. **Chemistry**

    0.62
36. **Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair**

    0.59
37. **Super User**

    0.57
38. **Signal Processing**

    0.55
39. **Ethereum**

    0.55
40. **Unix & Linux**

    0.54
41. **Information Security**

    0.53
42. **Database Administrators**

    0.53
43. **Travel**

    0.53
44. **Quantitative Finance**

    0.52
45. **Ask Ubuntu**

    0.50
46. **German Language**

    0.50
47. **Aviation**

    0.50
48. **Game Development**

    0.48
49. **Christianity**

    0.45
50. **Software Recommendations**

    0.45
51. **Webmasters**

    0.44
52. **Personal Finance & Money**

    0.44
53. **English Language & Usage**

    0.44
54. **Seasoned Advice**

    0.43
55. **Photography**

    0.43
56. **Ask Different**

    0.43
57. **Bicycles**

    0.43
58. **Arduino**

    0.43
59. **Philosophy**

    0.42
60. **Meta Stack Exchange**

    0.41
61. **Music: Practice & Theory**

    0.40
62. **Worldbuilding**

    0.39
63. **Cryptography**

    0.37
64. **Code Review**

    0.36
65. **Movies & TV**

    0.36
66. **Computer Science**

    0.36
67. Puzzling

    0.36
68. **Bitcoin**

    0.35
69. **Academia**

    0.33
70. **Raspberry Pi**

    0.32
71. **The Workplace**

    0.31
72. **User Experience**

    0.30
73. **Graphic Design**

    0.30
74. **Network Engineering**

    0.29
75. **Android Enthusiasts**

    0.28
76. **Data Science**

    0.26
77. **Web Applications**

    0.20
78. **Software Engineering**

    0.19

Comment: I was thinking of this in a different context. I think Judaism is very special in that we lean through Q&A. If you think of it, this is not how you learn about other disciplines. I don't think there are dozens of books of Q&A on history, science or arts. I'd say this is one of the key causes of what you detected.

Comment: It could mean we have high user retention. Maybe that we have a few outliers with lots of questions. It's hard to conclude much from one single statistic.

Comment: It might be interesting to display these results with the number of users of each group.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I don't think I saved that data.